# Why is this question a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Today I asked a question regarding [date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631696/best-ways-to-solve-date-time-license-issue) the community marked it as duplicate stating that [it is already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532540/c-how-to-make-it-harder-for-hacker-cracker-to-get-around-or-bypass-the-licensi)

The question which they refered list out the license key issues, but my question is regarding date/time issues, can anyone give me the clarification why my question was marked as duplicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that this is a different question. And you already have two good solutions (one in comment one as an answer).

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if it is a duplicate or not. But in general, if your question gets closed as duplicate, and and the answers in the linked question do not solve your problem, you should edit your question clearly explaining why they do not solve your problem. After the edit, the question will be bumped, and it will appear in the reopen queue, where it will be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

This definitely looks like a mistake. Your question is different. However I would suggest to search for questions about making trial versions of software. Here is one possible example: [How to create trial version of .NET software?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2423976/1249581).

I vote for question reopen.

Comment: thanks for the support now the question was reopened :)